# 1 and 2 marks on Ravel's La Valse two-piano version

Tags: notation

I found [1] and [2] marks on Ravel, "La Valse" two piano version (by Garban), like

[image: "La Valse", piano score, mm. 7–13 and mm. 27–32]

Only [1] or [2] is written during the whole piece, not [3] or [4], etc. so they are not rehearsal marks.
No notes for these marks and also orchestra and piano solo versions haven't got them.

What do they mean?

Comment: Are you *sure* they're not (badly distributed) rehearsal marks? For example, if there is a separate series of A, B, C, etc., then *those* would almost certainly be rehearsal marks and the 1 and 2 would not. Without that separate series (or similar 1's and 2's elsewhere), I cannot eliminate the possibility that the 1 and 2 are the *only* rehearsal marks in the entire piece.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Thanks for your comment. It has got actually rehearsal marks as \[A], \[B], \[C]... but 1 and 2 I asked here are written multiple times in the whole piece, e.g. 1, 1, 2, 1, 2...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

The multiple [1]s and [2]s are an error in the score. They do in fact correspond to the rehearsal marks in the orchestral score, but are mis-numbered.

There should also be [A] and [B], but those should be the only letter markings.

---

All images and other references come [from IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/La_valse_(Ravel%2C_Maurice)). Ravel's arrangement was used for this post, rather than Garban's as in the OP, to reinforce the errors, which are contained in both arrangements.

## The [1]s and [2]s

Without being exhaustive, what follows is an illustration of how the piano score boxed numbers are intended to refer to the rehearsal marks in the orchestral score, but do so incorrectly.

#### The first piano-score [1] correctly corresponds to the orchestra score

In the orchestra score, [1] occurs at m. 12, and in the images below, we can see that the piano score's [1], also at m. 12, corresponds.

**Orchestral score m. 12**
[image: "La Valse", image from orchestral score m. 12]

**Piano score m. 12**
[image: "La Valse", image from piano score m. 12]

#### Markings go astray, however, beginning with [2] and [3] in the orchestral score, but not the piano.

In the orchestral score, [2] occurs at m. 18, followed by [3] at m. 24. The music in the piano score corresponds to these same measures, but the rehearsal marks are omitted. Excerpts from measure 18 of each score are shown below.

**Orchestral score m. 16–18**
[image: orchestral score mm. 16–18]

**Piano score mm. 16–18**
[image: piano score mm. 16–18]

#### Right place, wrong marking

Where the piano score catches up, sort of, is in measure 34. At that point, the piano score again indicates [1], while the orchestral score, in m. 35 (the piano score omits a measure of tremolo) indicates [4].

**Orchestral score m. 35**
[image: Orchestral score m. 35]

**Piano score m. 34**
[image: Piano score m. 34]

#### Another right place, wrong marking

The next marking in the piano score, [2] at measure 39, corresponds to [5] at measure 40 in the orchestral score. The orchestral score's [6] comes at measure 45, and [7] occurs at measure 51. However, the piano score's [2] is 11 bars long — encompassing both [5] and [6] in the orchestral score — and then we encounter a second [1] at the same point as the orchestra's [7].

**Orchestral score m. 51**
[image: Orchestral score m. 51]

**Piano score m. 50**
[image: Piano score m. 50]

#### And so forth ...

## The [A] and [B]

These markings are explained in a preamble that appears in both the orchestral and piano scores. Here is the English translation that appears in the piano score.

> Drifting clouds part and allow hazy glimpses of waltzing couples. They gradually dissipate, and we can distinguish [A] an immense ballroom filled with a whirling crowd.

> The scene continues to clear. The glow of the chandeliers shines to a full splendor [B].

> An Imperial Court ball, circa 1855.

Comment: https://music.stackexchange.com/users/70803/aaron Thank you for your splendid answering over my expectation. I couldn't believe in such errata as anybody notices so I asked here thinking of meaningful special marks for two-piano.
I meant actually not Garban's but Ravel's however you found I took a screen shot of Garban's by mistake. Oddly enough the same audacious errors in them means Garban followed Ravel's marking somehow?